# Как переопределить возможные значения ManyToManyField в InlineModelAdmin с учётом значения другого поля инлайн-формы?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, eav

1. Товары относятся к категориями
2. Категории имеют фильтры с возможными значениями
3. Товары имеют атрибуты с теми же возможными значениями

Как переопределить инлайн-поля ManyToManyField в редактировании товара так, чтобы выбор значений атрибута соответствовал набору значений фильтра?

Метод formfield_for_manytomany класса admin.TabularInline где-то вызывается в цикле и получает как аргумент только отдельное поле (db_field) отдельной инлайн-формы.

Мне же для переопределения выборки нужно в этом методе иметь доступ к соседнему полю (filter) инлайн-формы и его набору значений (filter.variant_set).

Как можно пробросить в этот метод значения соседних полей той же инлайн-формы? Какой метод переопределить?

1. models.py (в сокращении)

   ```
   class Category(MPTTModel):  # Категория
       name = models.CharField('название', max_length=64)


   class Product(models.Model):  # Товар
       category = TreeForeignKey(Category, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='категория')

       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           # тут кастомная логика с авто-удалением/добавлением атрибутов товарам


   class VariantFilter(models.Model):  # Фильтр категории
       name = models.CharField('имя фильтра', max_length=64)
       category = TreeForeignKey(Category, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='категория')

       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           # тут кастомная логика с автодобавлением атрибутов товарам


   class Variant(models.Model):  # Значения атрибутов товаров
       value = models.CharField('значение', max_length=64)
       filter = models.ForeignKey(VariantFilter, models.CASCADE)


   class VariantAttribute(models.Model): #  Атрибут товара
       product = models.ForeignKey(Product, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='товар')
       filter = models.ForeignKey(VariantFilter, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='атрибут')
       values = models.ManyToManyField(Variant, blank=True, verbose_name='значения')

       class Meta:
           unique_together = (('product', 'filter'),)
   ```
2. admin.py (в сокращении)

   ```
   # Инлайн-поля со значениями фильтров
   class VariantInline(admin.TabularInline):
       model = Variant
       extra = 1


   # Редактирование фильтра
   @admin.register(VariantFilter)
   class VariantFilterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       inlines = [VariantInline]


   # Инлайн-поля с атрибутами товаров
   class VariantAttributeInline(admin.TabularInline):
       model = VariantAttribute
       max_num = 0
       fields = ('filter', 'values',)
       readonly_fields = ('filter',)

       def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
           return False

       def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
           # тут нужно ограничить выбор значений атрибута товара
           # для этого сюда НУЖНО ПРОКИНУТЬ соседнее поле filter,
           # чтобы достать его набор значений (variant_set)
           field = super(VariantAttributeInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
           if db_field.name == 'values':
               print(field)
           return field


   # Редактирование товара
   @admin.register(Product)
   class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       model = Product
       inlines = [VariantAttributeInline]
   ```

Спасибо, что обратили внимание на вопрос.

Буду рад любым предложенным решениям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

1. переопределить ModelForm для TabularInline
2. переопределить __init__ у ModelForm
3. переопределить queryset для values с фильтрацией по filter

```py
    class VariantAttributeForm(ModelForm):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(VariantAttributeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            if 'instance' in kwargs:
                self.fields['values'].queryset = Variant.objects.filter(filter=kwargs['instance'].filter)

        class Meta:
            model = VariantAttribute
            fields = '__all__'

    class VariantAttributeInline(admin.TabularInline):
        form = VariantAttributeForm
```